# Deploying a mean.io app to Heroku

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku, express, mean.io

I'm having trouble with the deployment of a mean.io application to Heroku. This post describes the steps I've taken to create the application and to try to deploy it. What am I doing wrong?

First, I start a Mongo daemon process:

```
$ mongod
```

Then create a mean.io application:

```
$ npm install -g mean-cli
$ mean init myNewApp
> app name? myNewApp
> help us improve the mean network? n
> set up first admin user? y
  > email: user@example.com
  > pass: mypassword
$ cd myNewApp
$ mean postinstall
$ npm install
$ bower install
$ gulp
```

The default mean.io gulp task starts a local webserver, and I'm able to login to the application. The next step is to create a Heroku application:

```
$ heroku create # this creates https://shrouded-stream-2828.herokuapp.com
```

And add a MongoDB add-on from compose.io. This was accomplished following these steps:

```
# In the Heroku web console, select the Heroku application.
# Click edit Add-ons, find Compose MongoDB, and press save. 
# Click on "Compose MongoDB" link, click the "Admin" tab
# Click the "Users" tab, click the "Add user" button, adding the user:
  db.addUser('​meanadmin','​mypassword')
# And hit the "Add user" button to actually add the user.
# Copy the URL from the Overview tab:
mongodb://meanadmin:mypassword@candidate.2.mongolayer.com:10479,candidate.3.mongolayer.com:10419/app15307042
```

With this URL, navigate to /path/to/myNewApp/config/env/production.js in a text editor and replace the values of the "db" property with the Mongo URL above, as in:

```
db: 'mongodb://' + (process.env.DB_PORT_27017_TCP_ADDR || 'localhost') + '/mean-prod',

becomes...

db: 'mongodb://meanadmin:mypassword@candidate.2.mongolayer.com:10479,candidate.3.mongolayer.com:10419/app15307042',
```

Commit the changes, and push to Heroku:

```
$ git add .
$ git commit -m 'adding mongodb'
$ git fetch --unshallow
$ git push heroku master
$ heroku open
```

After a long pause, this results in the following error:

```
Application Error
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. Please try again in a few moments.
If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.
```

How do I deploy this application to Heroku? I'm not sure if I copied the Mongo URL to the correct place, for instance. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you provide the logs? Type:
heroku logs in your console

Comment: I followed your steps and get an error when I push my code...

`Counting objects: 379, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (282/282), done.
error: RPC failed; result=22, HTTP code = 400
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
Writing objects: 100% (379/379), 1.45 MiB | 288.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 379 (delta 31), reused 371 (delta 29)
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date`  can you check that the push ended successfuly?